# ADC susceptibility to EMI from cellphone source

Tags: adc, noise, emc

I'm having trouble with EMI induced noise in my prototype ADC project. The ADC functions well in all tests but my (admittedly unscientific) test of placing my cellphone beside the PCB or the power leads between the PCB and bench supply causes a big increase in the noise floor (~40dB) measured with the single-ended input shorted to ground. The interference is absent if the cellphone is in airplane mode.

The ADC is the LTC2512-24 and uses the LTC6363 driver, and is for an application that deals solely with audio range frequencies (20Hz-20kHz).

For PCB layout I followed the general approach I observed on the [DC2222 eval board](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/dc2222a-a.html) including:

- 4 layer stackup: signal with ground fill, power, ground, signal with ground fill
- ground plane stitching
- symmetry in the analog section
- mostly the same components (different voltage reference) including bypass caps
- similar component placement
- keeping traces as short as possible

My searches on the topic generally lead to a lot of theory, PCB layout recommendations (many that I've already implemented), and references to obscure RF test procedures / equipment that sound inaccessible to me (with a hobbyist budget).

Are there any general diagnostic techniques that can help to identify the path where RF coupling is occurring that are likely to be practical without a sophisticated facility?

Schematic and Layout here:

- [Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nniDIhIg4aczcGbFzuFf7DDSKGoG2RU_/view?usp=sharing)
- [Layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LpHyXdfAzPSeStsihDQRtMz80Fda3Gc-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just placing a cellphone beside it? Or does the cellphone need to be ringing? What if you put the cellphone in airplane mode? Is the noise still there?

Comment: `my prototype ADC project` - show the schematic and the layout.

Comment: @DKNguyen does not need to be ringing, just placed adjacent.

Comment: Try the airplane mode thing. Maybe it's not the cellphone communications but the switching regulators inside.

Comment: @DKNguyen the phone does not need to ring to cause problems. It still periodically communicates with the base station, and also there may be WLAN and Bluetooth going on. Even if those are disabled the capacitive screen handling may cause noise.

Comment: @Justme I know but I'm trying to rule out the radio. You can also enable airplane mode and then re-enable selective wireless facilities while airplane mode is enabled in certain OSs. That would let you narrow down which radio is causing the problem if it is the radio at all. There also exists the RF Explorer which might help.

Comment: No interference with airplane mode ON

Comment: Well that is good info. Maybe a shield cover? Or a ferrite bead inserted directly at the ADC input pin? You might be able to cut into your board and scrape to test that. Unless it's coupling somewhere else like the reference or ground lines. I'm not sure how well any of these work though and you kind of need to know the frequency. You could also via fence but I don't think you have enough layers for that.

Comment: Also, proximity of the cellphone to the power leads between bench supply and PCB seems to cause the issue. Goal is to add a cell module to the design so not sure how effective a shield cover would be with a future internal RF source.

Comment: @davegravy The shield doesn't cover everything. Only the parts that matter and power line issues theoretically could be alleviated with ferrites

Comment: @Justme Disabling Bluetooth makes the biggest difference, followed by LTE. Wifi seems to make no difference. With all 3 disabled there is still some noise and I can't find any other radios I can easily disable in the android OS (Google Pixel) without using airplane mode

Comment: @davegravy I wonder why Bluetooth is so much worse than WiFi since they share the same band.

Comment: The WiFi might be using 5Ghz instead of 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

The cellphone chatters on RF all the time. And the farther it is from the base station, the more power its radios will be transmitting at.

The phone’s RF is coupling to your board as common mode noise. The board circuitry unhelpfully rectifies this noise into signal. This is the same problem that plagues audio gear, causing that annoying ‘buzz’ whenever a cellphone is nearby.

A few things you can try:

- add small-value caps from the board power and I/O points to ground
- Add common mode filters to the connections
- Shield the board in an enclosure

Some ideas here: https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/electronics-design-guides/minimise-electromagnetic-interference-medical-devices

That said, unless you’re willing to invest time and money into your design, it may be reasonable to stipulate that you need to keep cellphones and other strong interferers away from your prototype setup.

Comment: I thought caps aren't effective at the RF frequencies involved?

Comment: If they’re small ones they can have some effect.